# Prevent React setState from batching updates

Tags: reactjs

I'm calling a function `createSession` when a user clicks on a button.

In `createSession` I run:

```
this.setState({divClass: 'show'}, function() {
  ...computationally intensive and async stuff 
})
```

By changing `this.state.divClass` to `'show'` the DOM is supposed to be re-rendered and show a div that previously had a class of `'hide'`

I've dropped a console.log in the render function to make sure that setState is in fact re-rendering before it does the `other stuff`. Even though the console is showing the component has re-rendered, the view does not change until other stuff finishes.

What I'm confused about is that the component is being re-rendered before the callback is called, but the changes won't display until the callback is finished.

I'm using version 13.0 of React

---

Here is some code (sorry, it's in coffee):

```
crypto = require('crypto')

Component = React.createClass({

  render: ->
    <button onClick={@showDiv}>Show Div</button>
    <div className={@state.divDisplay}>
      Wooo
    </div>

  getInitialState: -> {
    divDisplay: 'hide'
  }


  showDiv: ->
    @setState({divDisplay: 'show'}, ->
      salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')

      # this call is not really sync
      crypto.pbkdf2('password', salt, 10000, 32, 'sha1', (error, hash) ->
        console.log error, hash
      )
    )
})
```

---

UPDATE (and personal solution)

I found that the problem was not that React was batching its updates to the state - I was using a password hashing library that ran synchronously. The library would block the UI from updating. So even though the render call would console.log that the state had changed, the UI was not able to update.

I ended up using a web worker to hash the password in the background. This allowed the rest of the UI to operate as usual.

Comment: Please include enough code to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have typo in `render()`. Should be `@state.divDisplay` instead of `@divDisplay`.

Comment: thanks, I just fixed the typo. But this was just an example and not the actual code that I'm using.

Comment: I can't reproduce described behavior with the code you provided. It works fine for me. Can you please provide [minimal reproducible example](http://sscce.org/)?